# CSS3 body section

Tags: css, media-queries

I trying to make a responsive website, and I've got a problem with body section.

I did this :

```
    body{
         width: 1500px;
        }

        @media (max-width: 768px) {

            body{ 
            width: 1000px;

        }}
```

And well, the problem is that it doesn't work.

And ideas why ?

Comment: It does work: http://jsbin.com/AFihagO/1 (resize browser window)

Comment: No it doesn't... the problem was solve bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll point out that you have `max_width: 768px;` and your is:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

        body{ 
        width: 1000px;

    }
}
```

Give this a shot:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

        body{ 
        width: 768px;

    }
}
```